# mysql: count() is slow when using multiple table query

Tags: mysql

when I use a MySQL query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM orders
```

it takes 0.183 s

if I use the query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM orders
LEFT  JOIN order_items ON (`orders`.`StoreOrderId` = order_items.StoreOrderId)
LEFT  JOIN seller_accounts ON (`orders`.`seller_id` = seller_accounts.seller_id)
```

it takes 4.793 s

after explain:

```
{table:orders,          select_type:simple, type:index, key_len:166, rows:841683, extra:using index}
{table:seller_accounts, select_type:simple, type:ref,   key_len:83,  rows:1, extra:using index}
{table:order_items,     select_type:simple, type:ref,   key_len:83,  rows:1, extra:using index}
```

this count() query is used for PHP pagination, I need to know how many records are in the database so that I can know how many pages.

but count() query took me  4.793s, which is too long, who can I make it faster?

Comment: Performance question need a EXPLAIN of the queries and  create table for all tables invoved

Comment: Are you using indexes correctly?

Comment: please check my explain,  I am using index and  type is index or ref,  seem not bad

Comment: I can't really think that this query does anything useful.

Comment: what are you trying to count?  with the order_items join, your count of orders becomes a count of order items.  and then the seller_accounts join multiplies it by the number of accounts the seller_id has (which maybe is always one)?  anyway, what you are trying doesn't look like it makes a whole lot of sense; back up and describe what you want your query to do

Answer (score 2):

First, I will answer your Question.

The single-table `COUNT` finds the smallest index and scans straight through it.

The multiple-table `COUNT` works something like this:

1. For each row in `orders`...
2. Reach into `order_items` using `StoreOrderId`, one row at a time.  Hopefully, that column is indexed.
3. Ditto for `seller_accounts`.

Note that scanning an index with 841683 items is a lot faster than looking up each one of 841683 (or more or less) one at a time.

Now I will rip into the question.

These indexes are needed for the `JOINs`:

```
 order_items:      INDEX(StoreOrderId)
 seller_accounts:  INDEX(seller_id)
```

Are there multiple "items" in an order?  Then the second `JOIN` will give a bigger `COUNT(*)`.  Hence it is reasonable for it to take more time.

You want users to paginate through 841683 orders???

If there is a `WHERE` clause or anything else, *we need to see it in order to advise on performance*.  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Why are the ids 83 bytes?

Answer (score 0):

instead of star use some column

```
SELECT count(order_items) FROM orders
LEFT  JOIN order_items ON (`orders`.`StoreOrderId` = order_items.StoreOrderId)
LEFT  JOIN seller_accounts ON (`orders`.`seller_id` = seller_accounts.seller_id)
```

Comment: `*` simply says count the rows.  `order_items` says to count only rows where `order_items` is `NOT NULL`.  `*` is _usually_ the better approach.

Comment: Furthermore `*` can use any index; `COUNT(order_items)` must use an index that contains that column -- or default to the entire table, which is probably bulkier.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT 'Orders' table name, COUNT(*) rows
FROM orders
UNION
SELECT 'OrderItems'' table name, COUNT(*) rows
FROM order_items
UNION
SELECT 'SellerAcc' table name, COUNT(*) rows
FROM seller_accounts